# Guidance on HTTP POST Request

Tags: http, post, request, mechanize, mechanicalsoup

I need to update the page number on this page and any like it on the same site:
http://architects-register.org.uk/towns/Bedfordshire/Ampthill

The code from the page to make this happen looks like this:

```
href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$mainContent$ArchitectsTable1$lvRegistrants$dpTopRight$ctl00$ctl00&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Next</a>
```

I'm new to http POST request and don't know what I need to do.

Using python 3.5.2, have installed both mechanize 0.2.5 (active version) and mechanize0.2.6 but visual studio is throwing errors when trying to load mechanize. 
Because of this, I've installed [Mechanical Soup](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup) but not sure what to do with it in order to achieve my aims. Been going round in circles for hours so any help appreciated!